# How would you translate "join", as in "join us" or "join the dead heroes" (i. e. "die in a war")?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, syntax

I am trying to translate the lyrics of the [Eric Bogle's song The Green Fields of France](https://youtu.be/iYCxeY8wTLU). In the first stanza, you have:

> I see by your gravestone, you were only nineteen
> when you **joined** the dead heroes in 1915.

How would you translate that to Latin? In English, obviously, you use "join"+accusative. So, a literal translation from English would be:

> Video tuo monumento tibi fuisse solummodo undeviginti annos,
> cum tu iunxisti mortuos heroes anno 1915-o.

However, I can't help but notice that such a literal translation from English wouldn't be a proper Croatian sentence. In Croatian, you say:

> Vidim ti po spomeniku, bilo ti je samo 19 godina,
> kad si **se pridružio** mrtv**im** heroj**ima** 1915. godine.

So, for that, in Croatian, you use "pridružiti" + "se" (the reflexive pronoun) + dative. In other words, in Croatian, you say "join yourself to". So, a literal translation from Croatian would be:

> Video tuo monumento tibi fuisse solummodo undeviginti annos,
> cum tu te iunxisti mortuis heroibus anno 1915-o.

I guess none of that is proper Latin. So, what is the proper Latin for that?

Comment: How about  the verb "coaduno"?

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças Well, for one thing, "coaduno" is Late Latin. Is there really no way of saying "Come and join us!" in the Classical Latin? Google Translate says it is "Coniunge nobis!", and that seems plausible to me. What do you think, is that correct?

Comment: Do you know/have the English-latin dictionary by William Smith and Theophilus? It's the only English-latin dictionary I know.

Comment: @ManuelCauãRebouças Never heard of it.

Comment: https://books.google.com.br/books?id=AWDuuiDEXOQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=english-latin+dictionary+by+william+Smith+and+Theophilus&hl=pt-BR&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&source=gb_mobile_search&ovdme=1&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=english-latin%20dictionary%20by%20william%20Smith%20and%20Theophilus&f=false   I hope it helps you. It has helped me for years

Comment: There are tons of different ways to translate it. Most Latin equivalents of English _join_ are going to lean very hard on literal _binding_ and _yoking_, which I assume is not actually the feeling you're going for. Is there an image you're trying to capture with more detail than just _were added to_ (_addere_)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like all poetry, it depends on the image you're going for. You probably don't actually want *anything* with the literal binding and yoking that you'll get with direct translation of *join*.

Some quick ideas would be

...*when you **added** yourself to their number*... (*addidsti*/*adderes*)
...*when you **increased**/**swelled** their number*... (*increvisti*/*incresceres* &c. &c.)
evoking the image of the impersonal ledgers kept by the generals;

...*when you **left** with the other heroes*... (*abisti*/*abires* &c. &c. &c.)
...*when you **crossed over** with the rest*... (*transisti*/*transires* &c.)
...*that you with so many boys **became** a hero*... (*factus est*/*sit*)
...*when you and so many **were** by death **made heroes***... (*heroificati sunt*/*sint*)
using various verbs to show the boy joined the others in some specific place or way;

...*when you with all the heroes **died***... (*cessisti*/*cesseris* &c. &c. &c.)
...*when you and other heroes **grew quiet***... (*quievisti*/*quieris*)
which normally would be too on the nose but here you're just moving the lazy 'dead' from the adjective for the other boys to the verb. Since Latin *normally* has the verb towards the end, it allows you to make the first part of the line extol the boy and his fellow heroes before hammering that bitter coffin nail in.